# What are valid table names in SQLite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

What are the combination of characters for a table name in SQLite to be valid? Are all combinations of alphanumerics (A-Z, a-z and 0-9) constitute a valid name?

```
Ex. CREATE TABLE 123abc(...);
```

What about a combination of alphanumerics with dashes "-" and periods ".", is that valid as well?

```
Ex. CREATE TABLE 123abc.txt(...);
Ex. CREATE TABLE 123abc-ABC.txt(...);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

I haven't found a reference for it, but table names that are valid without using brackets around them should be any alphanumeric combination that doesn't start with a digit:

```
abc123 - valid
123abc - not valid
abc_123 - valid
_123abc - valid
abc-abc - not valid (looks like an expression)
abc.abc - not valid (looks like a database.table notation)
```

With quoted names you should be able to use pretty much anything as a table name:

```
"This should-be a_valid.table+name!?"
```

SQLite also supports quoting in SQL Server and MySQL style:

```
[This should-be a_valid.table+name!?]

`This should-be a_valid.table+name!?`
```

Comment: Just another follow up question. Would the parenthesis rule also apply to column names? For instance, SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE [column.name] = 1;

Comment: @David: I don't know definitely about SQLite, but in all other databases I have used you can use column names like that.

Comment: aren't brackets some sort of quoting? e.g. "abc-abc" also should work.

Comment: @dashesy: Yes, that should work. What you can use for quoting depends on the database and its settings.

Comment: I find that the name 'transaction' can't be a valid table name in sqlite3:
sqlite> create table transaction (id integer primary key);
Error: near "transaction": syntax error

Comment: @KedarMhaswade: Yes, there are reserved keywords that you can't use as identifiers without quoting them, as they are recognised as the keyword instead of as an identifier.

Comment: Apparently, "Index" is not a valid column name in SQLite3, either.

Comment: Seems like the square brackets (as well as double-quotes) don't do the trick anymore in SQLite3. I'm trying to do this with hyphenated table name in PHP+PDO+SQLite3, and I'm getting `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "-": syntax error`.

Comment: Using brackets around the table name throws error:-
`SQL <CREATE TABLE (table1);> threw error: near "(": syntax error`

@MatthewFlaschen has correct answer, use of double quotes.

Comment: @MatWalker: Yes, quotes seems to be the preferred way in SQLite. It supports brackets (SQL Server compatibility) and grave accents (MySQL compatibility), but that might be possible to disable in settings.

Answer (score 35):

All of these are allowed, but you may have to quote them in `""`.

```
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc"(col);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc.txt"(col);
sqlite> CREATE TABLE "123abc-ABC.txt"(col);
sqlite> select tbl_name from sqlite_master;
123abc
123abc.txt
123abc-ABC.txt
```

In general, though, you should stick to the alphabet.

Comment: Double-quotes are the standard quoting mechanism, not square brackets - https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html

Comment: Right, SQLite complained while dealing with a tutorial that had 'create table transaction ...' to model a 'bank transaction' and that was because 'transaction' is a keyword 'which may not be used as the names of tables, indices, columns, databases, user-defined functions, collations, virtual table modules, or any other named object' -- from your link!

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer.  With brackets around the tables names a syntax error is thrown.

Answer (score 7):

From SQLite [documentation on CREATE TABLE](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html), the only names forbidden are those that begin with `sqlite_` :

> Table names that begin with "sqlite_" are reserved for internal use. It is an error to attempt to create a table with a name that starts with "sqlite_".

Answer (score 6):

Per Clemens on the sqlite-users mailing list:

Everything is allowed, except names beginning with "sqlite_".

```
CREATE TABLE "TABLE"("#!@""'☺\", "");
```

You can use keywords ("TABLE"), special characters (""#!@""'☺\"), and even the empty string ("").

Answer (score 0):

If you use periods in the name you will have issues with your SQL Queries.  So I would say avoid those.