# SQLite issue with Table Names using numbers?

Tags: sql, sqlite, numbers

I'm developing an app which requires that the user selects a year formatted like this **1992-1993** from a spinner. The tablename is also named **1992-1993** and the idea is that using SQL the values from this table are pulled through with a statement like this **select * from 1992-1993**. When I run the emulator however, it throws an error.

If I then relabel the Spinner item to **NinetyTwo** and rename the table to **NinetyTwo** and run the emulator it runs as expected and the data is pulled through from the table.

Does SQLite have an issue with numbers in table names?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What are valid table names in SQLite?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite)

Answer (score 7):

Yes and No. It has an issue with numbers at the beginning of a table name. `1992-1993` is an expression returning `-1`. Try to rename the table to `Year1992`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite) a similar issue on SO.

Comment: ...or, put the table name in strings, like `"1992-1993"` or `\`1992-1993\`` or `'1992-1993'` (I'm not sure which SQLite uses).

Comment: With SQLite you can use `"` or `[..]`.

Comment: That's great. Thanks for taking the time to explain

Answer (score 0):

sorry for late post

There may be a deeper issue here - is the structure you are using (table name per item in spinner) the best one for the job?

You may find that you want a number of tables e.g.

spinner_value (id, value)
form_data(id, spinner_value_id, etc ....)