# SQLiteException: near "-": syntax error

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm getting this exception when doing a create view sentence:

```
04-10 10:09:55.475: E/AndroidRuntime(15451): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.mo.activity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "-": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE VIEW vNa-MarcadbRESID1dataV18 AS SELECT * FROM ITEMS WHERE 1  AND ( 1 != 1 OR Column7 = 1 )
```

Where is the problem?

vNa-MarcadbRESID1dataV18 is not a valid name for a View in sqlite?

Comment: This [should help](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3694305/2345913)

Comment: Your table name `vNa-MarcadbRESID1dataV18` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Identifiers such as view names cannot contain `-` - it parses as subtraction expression. Either rename it or quote it in `` `backticks` `` or `"double quotes"`.

Comment: Identifiers [are quoted with `"double quotes"`](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html); backticks are supported only for bug-compatibility with MySQL.