# How to do query on database table name containing the minus sign (-) in java?

Tags: java, android, database

I have a table name, inside a database, called (ie) : `ARI5-v006`

The minus sign appears to be a problem.

Here's the query code:

```
String table_name="ARI5-v006";
Cursor dataCount = bdd.rawQuery("select * from " + table_name, null);
```

It causes an error.

Here's the logcat:

```
Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "-": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: select * from ARI5-v006
```

I've tried add quote to the table_name.... but not working.

Any idea?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite

Comment: Make back ticks arround the table name.

Comment: I've do this:  `Cursor dataCount = bdd.rawQuery("select * from " + "'"+table_name+"'", null);` but LogCat said the table isn't found: `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: ARI5-v006 (code 1): , while compiling: select * from 'ARI5-v006'`.

Answer (score 2):

You can:

1. Change the table name and use '_' instead of '-'
2. Try quoting the table name in square braces. Ex: "select * from [ARI5-v006]" --> bdd.rawQuery("select * from [" + table_name + "]", null);

Comment: 1, I can't change the name, and i've try `"select * from [ARI5-v006]"`, not working ;)