# No such table when table is clearly there - SQ-Lite

Tags: android, sqlite

I have the following query:

```
cursor = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("select _id, Likert-Skala from "+inAd+" where Name like ?" ,
            new String[] { "%" + str2 + "%" });
```

Now, I get a "no such table" error for Likert-Skala.
However, if I do this:

```
Cursor c = helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery("SELECT * FROM "+inAd+" ",  null);
    DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(c);
```

Then my result is, for instance:

```
09-30 18:42:11.212: I/System.out(907):    Likert-Skala=1.63
```

So the table is clearly there, and there is no typo. 
Anyone have an Idea?

Comment: i think the issue is your column name has a hyphen, which SQLite probably interprets as subtraction between two other terms.

Comment: if that is so, then why is the error message: "No such column: Likert Skala"? and when I ask for all the columns, "Likert-Skala" comes out fine?

Comment: I think you are passing the wrong string it should be: "SELECT _id FROM Likert-Skala" +inAd+ "WHERE Name like ?"

Comment: Because it thinks you are selecting an expression `(Likert - Skala)`, rather than a name "Likert-Skala". It tries to find an operand with the name "Likert" and subtract another operand with the name "Skala". I suggest renaming your columns to not include characters that sqlite may interpret as operators.

Answer (score 1):

You might have to do away with the "-" sign. Otherwise this should be fine:

```
String sql = "SELECT _id FROM Likert-Skala WHERE Name like ?";
String[] str = {"%" + str2 + "%"};
Cursor cursor = this.helper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(sql, str);
```

Comment: @newnewbie I came to understand that Likert_Skala is valid with "_" sign or [Likert-Skala] is valid with "[ ..]" brackets. Here is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite