# showing syntax error in create table command of sqllite database

Tags: android

```
String QUERY11 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + "(" + COL_DATE + " TEXT, " + COL_FAULT + " TEXT, " + COL_PARTREPLACE + " TEXT, " + COL_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " + COL_TECHNICIAN + " TEXT);";
```

when i used this line in my code then it give error like

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "5151": syntax error
>   (code 1): , while compiling: CREATE TABLE 5151(date TEXT, fault TEXT,
>   partReplace TEXT, amount TEXT, technician TEXT);

Answer (score 1):

Your TABLE_NAME is an Integer, you should use String

Answer (score 0):

**Table names that are valid without using brackets around them should be any alphanumeric combination that doesn't start with a digit:**

Check the accepted answer of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite) question

Answer (score 0):

You can't use numeric as first letter of table name, your table name start with a character or you can try this.

```
String QUERY11 = "CREATE TABLE '" + TABLE_NAME + "'(" + COL_DATE + " TEXT, " + COL_FAULT + " TEXT, " + COL_PARTREPLACE + " TEXT, " + COL_AMOUNT + " TEXT, " + COL_TECHNICIAN + " TEXT);";
```

Answer (score 0):

**Sql Table Name structure:**

- Only Alphanumeric characters and underline are allowed.
- The field name must begin with an alpha character or underline

  > abc123 - valid
  >
  > 123abc - not valid
  >
  > abc_123 - valid
  >
  > _123abc - valid