# How to access different SQLite database (schema) using JDBC

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

I have an application that uses an Oracle database.  It reads data out of the database using statements like:

> SELECT * from schema.table WHERE ...

I would like to create a SQLite database with data I can use for regression-testing the application.  It's simple enough to change the jdbc settings to get the application to connect to a different database, but the SQL statements need to be exactly the same.

I know when I run SQLite from the command line, I can attach a database using

> attach database  as

If I do that, then the same select statements that work in oracle to access a table in a different Oracle schema will work to access the data in a different SQLite database.  But, since I'm connecting via JDBC, I don't have the option to run the "attach database" command.

Is there a way to configure SQLite such that it will accept requests like the above?

I tried

> create table "schema.table" ...

That worked, but then I need to include the quotes in the select statement, which Oracle won't allow.

Comment: Does it have to be SQLite? Have you looked into other Java databases like HSQLDB that explicitly offer some degree of [Oracle compatibility](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/compatibility-chapt.html#coc_compatibility_oracle)?

Comment: Sounds like you are in a bit of a pickle. SQLite won't support a period in its table name without the quotes (reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite) and you can't user the quotes in the query. Looks like you'll have to modify the queries some how or use a different db implementation over sqlite

Comment: Why wouldn't JDBC allow you to execute an ATTACH statement?

Comment: I'm going with creating a View in Oracle that will allow me to access the tables without specifying a schema.  Using SQLite rather than some other database allows me to run tests locally without needing to install anything.