# Fatal error on android studio .how to fix?

Tags: android

This is my code:

```
    package com.example.user.sqliteapp2;

    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHelper myDb;
    EditText editName,editSurname,editMarks;
    Button btnAddData;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);

    editName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_name);
    editSurname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_surname);
    editMarks=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText_marks);
    btnAddData=(Button) findViewById(R.id.button_add);
    AddData();
    }
    public void AddData(){
    btnAddData.setOnClickListener(
    new View.OnClickListener(){
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Boolean inserted= myDb.insertData(editName.getText().toString(),
    editSurname.getText().toString(),
    editMarks.getText().toString());
    if (inserted==true )
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DATAINSERTed",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    else
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"DATAINSERTed",
    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    }
    );
    }
```

After compiling the app, I click on an `add data` button to insert some data. Then it show this fatal error:

```
    '[ 10-24 10:38:38.886  2439: 2439 D/         ]
    HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x7fc5fe207940,        tid 2439
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 42 frames!  The application may be doing too        much work on its main thread.
    E/SQLiteLog: (1) near "table": syntax error
    D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

    --------- beginning of crash
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main

    Process: com.example.user.sqliteapp2, PID: 2439

    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error(code 1):  -while compiling: create table student.table ( ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY                -#-AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,SURNAME TEXT,MARKS INTEGER )at -       android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method at         android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnect#        ion.java:887) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:498) 
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1674)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1605)
    at com.example.user.sqliteapp2.DatabaseHelper.onCreate(DatabaseHelper.java:26)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getDatabaseLocked(SQLiteOpenHelper.jav#a:251)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase(SQLiteOpenHelper.j#ava:163) 
    at com.example.user.sqliteapp2.DatabaseHelper.insertData(DatabaseHelper.java:36)
    at com.example.user.sqliteapp2.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) at         android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)'
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: take a look on how to insert record in sqlite. seems your query syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is in your DatabaseHelper, you need to name your table properly. Table name cannot contain `.`.

Check your logcat output `android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "table": syntax error(code 1):  -while compiling: create table student.table` it says you are attempting to create a table with name `student.table` which is invalid.

check this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3694305/5284441) for more details.

Comment: but i still cannot found what wrong on the student.table . even i delete the '.'

Comment: What is logcat saying now?

Comment: '.' pretty much signifies table inside a db

Comment: still with same error , after i replace the 'TABLE_NAME="student.table"' to "TABLE_NAME="student"' in table name.

Comment: Boss what logcat is saying now?

Comment: 1:50:57 PM Executing tasks: [:app:clean, :app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:prepareDebugUnitTestDependencies, :app:assembleDebug]
1:51:44 PM Gradle build finished in 46s 647ms
1:52:11 PM Instant Run re-installed and restarted the app

Comment: thisnis the event log

Comment: 10-25 05:53:37.159 1585-2631/system_process E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f3a60a0e760

Comment: 10-25 05:53:37.195 1914-2511/com.android.inputmethod.latin E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0x7f3a6661b270      10-25 05:53:37.380 1233-1649/? E/audio_hw_generic: Error opening input stream format 1, channel_mask 0010, sample_rate 16000      10-25 05:54:02.780 1935-1935/com.google.android.gms.persistent E/NetworkScheduler.ATC: Provided calling package not found: com.google.android.apps.photos     this is the logcat