# SQLite - display table names finishing by "_1"

Tags: regex, sqlite, sql-like

I am looking for a way to display table names I have in a database for which the name is ending by "_1".

I tried to use the command:

```
.tables '%_1';
```

Unfortunately the underscore symbol is used in the expression matching, so it returned me tables such as:
"125_1","125_11","125_21".
Only the first one is interesting in this example, I will not display the full result because there are hundreds of tables. So I tried something like this:

```
.tables '%_1' ESCAPE '_';
```

And it gave me the exact same result.
If you have a solution to overcome the problem of the underscore symbol, please post it.
remember that I have hundreds of tables with names following this pattern in regex: "^\d+_\d+$"

Comment: That is a horrible table design. You should really consider redesigning the whole thing.

Comment: It is maybe horrible but it is a valid way to do it, check this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3694276/what-are-valid-table-names-in-sqlite
If you have a better idea feel free to post it : in principle table contain data coming from 2 different series of numbers. So I simply wrote table names <1stserie>_<2ndserie>.
How would you have done this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not how the [ESCAPE clause](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#like) works. To search for an underscore, you must escape the underscore with the escape character:

```
LIKE '%#_1' ESCAPE '#'
```

Anyway, `.tables` is not an SQL command and ignores the ESCAPE clause. To do your own search, you have to run your own query:

```
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND name LIKE '%#_1' ESCAPE '#';
```

Comment: perfect ! And let's say now, I would like to display the content of all these tables in only one command how should I do this ?

Comment: To ask a question, use the "Ask Question" button.