# Select rows in data frame with partial match in values of column

Tags: r, subset, partial, sqldf

Suppose I have the following dataset

```
d <- data.frame(1:31, 31:1)
names(d) <- c("1st", "2nd")
```

And I want to select the columns where "3" occurs in the column named "1st" (i.e. column 3, 13 and 31 should be selected, but not column 1, 9, and 29).

```
sqldf("select * from d where 1st LIKE '%3%'")
```

gives me the error:

> Error: unrecognized token: "1st"

How can I selectively subset part of a data frame based on a partial match?

Desired output:

```
1st    2nd
3       29
13      19
31      1
```

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have *illegal* column names, wrap it in square brackets:

```
sqldf("select * from d where [1st] LIKE '%3%'")
#   1st 2nd
# 1   3  29
# 2  13  19
# 3  23   9
# 4  30   2
# 5  31   1
```

Regarding *illegal*:

- [What are valid table names in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3694276/680068)

> I haven't found a reference for it, but table names that are valid without using brackets around them should be any alphanumeric combination that doesn't start with a digit

Comment: Thanks, this works! What exactly makes the column names illegal? (i.e. why do I have to bracket them?)

Comment: @Icewaffle Starting with a number, updated the post